# Moving Communities with Change Sets

Tags: community, change-set

I am moving a community for the first time. I just refreshed the Partial Sandbox and there is nothing there at all.

I am getting bad error messages that make very little sense:

Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Networks

Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Moderation Rules

Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: User Criteria

Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Keyword Lists

I check this link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/networks_migrate_changesets.htm
and this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/networks_migrate_considerations.htm#unsupported

but neither really make mention of what I have missed.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not all community features are supported via change sets, there are still a lot of manual configurations to do

Comment: are you trying to deploy the template? I generally create a community manually and import the site file.

Answer (score 1):

In the new sandbox, try going into Setup > Communities and enable Communities. This is a prerequisite step to deploying Communities to an org.

Comment: I am getting the exact same validation errors. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @Student No - At that point it was still impossible. I setup a new community in production and then shifted what could be shift in the CS